# Selenide - found and fill the element

Tags: selenide

I failed to allocate following element via selenide (i need find and fill it with text (ID)  :

```
                 <tr>
                    <th class="col-md-3 basicPropertiesName">Id</th>
                    <td class="col-md-9">
                        <input class="form-control ng-pristine ng-valid ng-                   touched" ng-keypress="keypressHandler($event, 2)" ng-model="newInsight.id" placeholder="ID">
                    </td>
                </tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

Or maybe this?

```
$("input[ng-model='newInsight.id']").setValue(value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need something like this?

```
By(xpath("//input[@ng-model='newInsight.id']))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(By.xPath("//tr[./th[text()='Id']]")).find("input").setValue("some text)
```

or without additional find()

```
$(By.xPath("//tr[./th[text()='Id']]//input")).setValue("some text)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use following options using css selectors also.

```
String str="th[class*='basicPropertiesName']";
SelenideElement element =$(str);
```

or

```
String str="th:contains('Id')";
SelenideElement element =$(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

one important moment.. all from above would fail if your example is placed in `iframe` (i've faced with such issue last week).

required actions:

a) how to find out if `<tr>` is (or not) part of `iframe` >> locate your tr on page, right-click on it, and ensure that you have no `View frame source`

[example of page Inspect with iframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ZQwT.png)

if No such - try examples from above...
if There is one - see below

b) how to switch into `iframe`

- you have to findout frame name...

--- make r-click on object + `Inspert`

--- locate your `<tr>`

--- click on it into `Inspect`

--- in the bottom of `Inspert` you'd see whole tree till selected element

--- move to the top of tree and you'd see something like `iframe#framenamehere`

--- copy it

- before seaching your element add line like:

> WebDriverRunner.getWebDriver().switchTo().frame(here the value from
> prev. steps without #);

and search for your `<tr>`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you use the `th` text in your query, to better target the input element:

```
Selenide.$(Selectors.byXpath("//th[text()='Id']/following-sibling::td/input"));
```

**Note:** Better to assign a unique `id` to the `input` element (and to every element under test) to improve readability and maintenance of your code.